# Firestore Security Rules: How to create a rule that checks a list of objects?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Imagine a field called `specialtyList` which is a list of specialties that stores the specialties of a doctor, each doctor is a user of the App

`doctors` is the collection

`doctorId` is the documentID and the ID used on Firebase Authentication

The document contains the `specialtyList` field, which is a list of objects, like:

**/doctors/{doctorId}**

```
{
   fullName: "...",
   specialtyList: [
      {
         specialtyId: 1,
         isApproved: false
      },
      {
         specialtyId: 2,
         isApproved: false
      },
      {
         specialtyId: 3,
         isApproved: false
      }
   ]
}
```

A doctor can add his specialty in the list, but he can't change the `isApproved` value to `true`, only users with the "approvalManager" **role** on Firebase Authentication can do that, so the rules would be something like

```
match /doctors/{doctorId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.token.approvalManager == true ||
          request.auth.uid == doctorId;
    
      //problem:
      allow write: if request.auth.token.approvalManager == true || (
          request.auth.uid == doctorId &&
          request.resource.data.diff(resource.data)
                .changedKeys().hasAny([ "specialtyList" ]) == false
      );
}
```

the problem with my solution is that the doctor wouldn't be able to add a specialty even if he correctly sets the `isApproved` value to `false`

So my question is, how can I create a security rule where:

- The doctor can add a object in `specialtyList`
- The doctor cannot add a object with the `isApproved` value being `true`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is your `write` rule:

```
allow write: if request.auth.token.approvalManager == true || (
          request.auth.uid == doctorId &&
          (request.resource.data.specialtyList[0].isApproved == false)
      );
```

This rule is good if the doctor update only one `specialty` per change, since the index in the array is hardcoded to zero.

BTW, to add an object, you need to use the `set` function with the option of `merge` so it only update the `specialtyList` and not overwrite it.